# Chrome Extension Stops When Page Refreshes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, postmessage

I have written a chrome extension that works on a page that has a countdown. When the  countdown finishes, the site runs some xhr requests to update the page.

When the page is updated from the xhr request, my extension stops working.

I first tried setting a timeout on the content script, but this does not work.

I then tried getting it to wait in the background page until countdown is finished, then send a postMessage request back to the content script, but this does not work either.

Is there another way to keep the content script alive when the page refreshes?

I apologise that I can't be more specific and supply code, but the project is for a company that do not want details passed on at the moment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I can't get authorisation to post actual code, but here is how I pass messages from background to content:

content.js

```
var port = chrome.extension.connect({ name: "Background Sniper" });
port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
    //code goes here to test the msg
}
```

background.js

```
var port = chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
//code goes here
}
```

The webpage tells me an epoch time when the countdown ends, so in the background.js I set:

```
function(countdownEndTime){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        port.postMessgae("GO")
    }, new Date().getTime - countdownEndTime)
```

But for some reason the content.js never receives the "GO" message.

Comment: No chance to help here without relevant code. Please make [a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You may even solve this yourself while making it.

Comment: I'll see what I can do

Comment: I've update the question with some pseudo code

Comment: I'm afraid those snippets may not be enough. Inability to release actual code is understandable, but you need to make a _complete_ example, that demonstrates the problem AND is actually something we can load as an extension.

Comment: O, but could you answer this... Is it possible that without the webpage physically refreshing, could the content script be stopped? Either by xhr requests or javascript on the page itself?

Comment: Very hard to say just like that. Add more debugging code, e.g. `onDisconnect` listeners to the ports.